# How can I calculate the radius of a residue?

Tags: protein-structure, pdb

I want to read a PDB file and display/render the atoms using a graphics engine.

If I consider each residue in the protein as a solid sphere, what would be the radius of the sphere?

How can I calculate it? Or, is there any database for that?

Comment: You may want to check how existing molecular viewers (PyMOL, Jmol, Chimera, web-based viewers on RCSB, PDBe and PDBj websites) render it.

Comment: @marcin, I am developing my own software for learning ourposes.

Comment: Van der Waals radii are used to construct a special kind of molecular model called a space-filling model. These models are constructed by drawing each atom as a van der Waals sphere with the atom’s nucleus at the center of the sphere. taken from https://www.reed.edu/chemistry/ROCO/Geometry/space_filling.html not sure how to expand it to a full residue

Comment: @pippo1980, thanks! good information. :)

Comment: try this paper not sure why 5A radius is choosen https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Each-protein-is-modeled-as-a-union-of-spheres-of-radius-5-A-one-sphere-per-amino-acid_fig2_8614866 the picture seems OK to me tough

Comment: ok full article is for free; it states: "....However, it has been suggested that the 5 Å radius is appropriate to model the hydration shell around the protein
[19]. The problem of computing
r for such a model reduces
to computation of the distance to the surface of each sphere,
and taking the minimum over all spheres.... " Worth to notice article 19 its about globular protein, no idead if 5A rules could be extended to other kind of protein too

Comment: The protein is
represented as a union of spheres, each of radius 5 Å, and
centered on the C
a atom of each amino acid residue